# Pivoting , Dynamic columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables like these

LoanPrograms

```
Id  Name       
------------   
1   LP1        
2   LP2        
3   LP3
```

Channels

```
Id  Name
----------
4  Channel1
5  Channel2
6  Channel3
```

LoanProgramsChannels

```
LoanProgramId      Channelid  
----------------------
1                   4
1                   5
2                   4
```

I wanted to get data like these

```html
LoanProgarmNames   channel1 channel2  channel3
----------------   -------- --------  --------
LP1                 y            y       N
LP2                 y            N       N
LP3                 N            N       N
```

I am quite new to SQL, I know I have to use `PIVOT` to achieve these, but not sure how can I achieve in these scenario. Can anybody help on this ?

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are trying to achieve in the output.  It might help if you explained to make it clearer.

Comment: 'Y' and 'N'  in the channel columns against the loan programs represent whether that particular loan program has entry in 'LoanProgramChannels' table..

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to "fill in the gaps" the best way is to create a cartesian product using a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT A.NAME AS LOANPROGRAMNAME 
, B.NAME AS CHANNELNAME
, CASE WHEN C.CHANNELID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS LOANPROGRAMCHANNELS
FROM LOANPROGRAMS AS A
CROSS JOIN CHANNELS AS B
LEFT JOIN LOANPROGRAMSCHANNELS AS C
ON CAST(A.ID AS VARCHAR)+CAST(B.ID AS VARCHAR) = 
CAST(C.LOANPROGRAMID AS VARCHAR)+CAST(C.CHANNELID AS VARCHAR))
SELECT LOANPROGRAMNAME, [CHANNEL1], [CHANNEL2], [CHANNEL3]
FROM CTE
PIVOT(MAX(LOANPROGRAMCHANNELS) FOR CHANNELNAME IN ([CHANNEL1], [CHANNEL2], [CHANNEL3])) PIV
```

Once you've got the condition (Y/N) you can pivot the required columns, as done here.

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways to code this, but I believe the following will provide what you want:

```
declare @tbLoanPrograms table (
    ID int, Name varchar(12)
)

insert into @tbLoanPrograms (
    ID      , Name
)
values    (1, 'LP1')
        , (2, 'LP2')
        , (3, 'LP3')

declare @tbChannels table (
    ID int, Name varchar(12)
)

insert into @tbChannels (
    ID      , Name
)
values    (4, 'Channel1')
        , (5, 'Channel2')
        , (6, 'Channel3')

declare @tbLoanProgramsChannels  table (
    LoanProgramId int, Channelid int
)

insert into @tbLoanProgramsChannels (
    LoanProgramId      , Channelid
)
values    (1, 4)
        , (1, 5)
        , (2, 4)

select
    t.Name
    , Channel1 = max(Channel1)
    , Channel2 = max(Channel2)
    , Channel3 = max(Channel3)
from (
    select
        lp.Name
        , Channel1 =
                case
                when lpc.LoanProgramId is not null and lpc.Channelid = 4
                    then 'y'
                else 'N'
            end
        , Channel2 =
            case
                when lpc.LoanProgramId is not null and lpc.Channelid = 5
                    then 'y'
                else 'N'
            end
        , Channel3 =
            case
                when lpc.LoanProgramId is not null and lpc.Channelid = 6
                    then 'y'
                else 'N'
            end
    from
        @tbLoanPrograms lp
        left join @tbLoanProgramsChannels lpc on lpc.LoanProgramId = lp.ID
        left join @tbChannels c on c.ID = lpc.Channelid
) t
group by t.Name
```